# Using both JSR-303 and Traditional Bean Validation?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Is it possible to use both [JSR-303 bean validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) and [traditional validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) (a single validator class for the type) in Spring?  If so, what configuration is required to set this up?

I have tried the instructions on the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s07.html).

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new DualEntryValidator());
}

@RequestMapping(value="/dualEntry.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handlePost(@Valid DualEntryForm form, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("dualEntry", getCommonModel());

    if (!result.hasErrors()){
        //do logic
        return modelAndView;

    }else {
        modelAndView.addObject("dualEntryForm", form);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

I can get this to use my custom `Validator` *or* the JSR-303 validation, but not both.  If I have the initBinder present as in the example it uses the custom `Validator`.  If I remove it the JSR-303 bean validation is used.  How can I use *both*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've done that following the instructions here:

http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/

See the "Enjoy both worlds" section. Shortly, you explicitly run a JSR303 validation from a Spring validator, "joining" the results of JSR303 validations based on annotations and your custom validation logic.

Answer (score 8):

I realise this is quite old, but I got this to work with minimal disturbance to my code

Change `binder.setValidator(new DualEntryValidator());`

to

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(new DualEntryValidator());
}
```

With `setValidator()` you're replacing the JSR-303 validator with your one. With `addValidator()`, the JSR-303 validator is called and so is yours.

You need to make sure that your validator does not overlap with your JSR-303 `@NotNull`, `@Min`, `@Max`, etc. annotations otherwise you'll get duplicate error messages added.

Comment: This is what I am using, but I now need the `JSR-303` validator to be called *BEFORE* my `custom validator`. Is it possible to achieve that? My `custom validator` shouldn't even be called if the basic `JSR-303` validation fails (@NotNulls, etc)

Comment: My custom validator is throwing null pointer exception because the JSR-303 does not kick in before hand, thus null validation is not done before the custom validator is triggered

Comment: Doug, without a code example it's hard to see what's happening. Please post a new question in StackExchange with example code and stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides three handle for bean validation.

1.abstract class **AbstractPropertyValidationAnnotationHandler**

2.abstract class **AbstractMethodValidationAnnotationHandler**

3.abstract class **ClassValidationAnnotationHandler**

In this example i am implementing custom annotation  CustomAnnotationHandle

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
 Class CustomAnnotationHandle extends  Annotation{

    public abstract String value();

   }
```

To implement custom annotation for property validation we need to extend **AbstractPropertyValidationAnnotationHandler** Class.

AbstractPropertyValidationAnnotationHandler provides createValidationRule abstract  method

```
protected abstract AbstractValidationRule createValidationRule(Annotation annotation, Class class1, String s);
```

So,the extended class must provide implementation of

```
protected abstract AbstractValidationRule createValidationRule(Annotation annotation, Class class1, String s)
```

```
public class CustomPropertyAnnotationHandler extends AbstractPropertyValidationAnnotationHandler
{

    public CustomPropertyAnnotationHandler()
    {
        super(new Class[] {
           XXX.XXX.PackageLevle.CustomAnnotationHandle // as it takes array of custom annotation ,so we can pass more than one 
        // overwriting abstract method
        protected  AbstractValidationRule createValidationRule(Annotation annotation, Class class1, String s){
            CustomAnnotationHandle value = (CustomAnnotationHandle)annotation;
            return TestValidationRule(value.getValue());

            // as you can see it return AbstractValidationRule.So, we need a class to give our bean specific validation rule.In our case it is 

            //TestValidationRule
        }


    }
}

public class TestValidationRule extends AbstractValidationRule
{

    public TestValidationRule (String valuetest)
    {
     super();  
 this.valuetest = valuetest;
    }


Private String valuetest;


}
```

Spring provides AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader Class.This class is used for spring own  annotation for bean validation.

DefaultValidationAnnotationHandlerRegistry class is used as defaultHandlerRegistry.But if we need to provide our own annotaion then we

need to extend AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader and set our specific handleregistry via method 
setHandlerRegistry(new CustomPropertyAnnotationHandler());

Class DefaultValidationAnnotationHandlerRegistry is used to register spring own annotation for bean validation.It register bean by

calling registerPropertyHandler method of SimpleValidationAnnotationHandlerRegistry class.So for our custom annotation we need to

register  CustomPropertyAnnotationHandler by calling registerPropertyHandler method of SimpleValidationAnnotationHandlerRegistry class

```
public class OurBeanSpecificValidationLoader extends AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader
{

    public OurBeanSpecificValidationLoader ()
    {
super();
        setHandlerRegistry(new OurSpecificAnnotationHandleRegistery ());
    }


}

public class OurSpecificAnnotationHandleRegistery extends DefaultValidationAnnotationHandlerRegistry
{

    public OurSpecificAnnotationHandleRegistery ()
    {
        registerPropertyHandler(new CustomPropertyAnnotationHandler() );
    }
}
```

so you have your custom annotation for bean valiation.E.g

```
  @CustomAnnotationHandle(value = "test")
    private Object test;
```