# Spring validation : Custom validate @RequestBody based on criteria @RequestParam

Tags: spring, validation

I want to validate a requestbody with @Valid annotation.
In the method there is a @RequestParam value.
If this @RequestParam value "min" I want that a field, in requestbody, is mandatory. It's possible with annotations?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = ProductionResponse.URL, produces = JWSMessageConverter.JWS_MEDIA_TYPE_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ProductionResponse> richiestaProduzione(@RequestParam("issuerType") String issuerType,
        @RequestParam("issuerCode") String issuerCode, @RequestParam("procedureId") String procedureId,
        @Valid @RequestBody ProductionRequestResource requestBody) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug("POST " + ProductionResponse.URL);
  @Valid ProductionRequestResource fff = requestBody;
    requestBody.setProcedureResource(issuerType, issuerCode, procedureId);

    try {
        ProductionResponse response = produzioneService.richiestaProduzione(requestBody);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ProductionResponse.ko(requestBody, e.getMessage(), requestBody.getNun()));
    }
}
```

I want that the field issuerMunicipalityCode in the ProductionRequestResource is mandatory if issuerType is equal to "MIN".

Comment: Your question was kind of misleading, so formatted it.

Comment: You need to implement a custom validation for your scenario. You can find a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075683/spring-mvc-validator-annotation-custom-validation

Comment: yes, but how i can access to field issuerType that is in the request, and using it for validate my requestbody?

Comment: don't you have issuerType in ProductionRequestResource pojo object? If not, then you need to validate without using spring validation framework.

Comment: no, i don't have issuetype in productionrequestresource pojo. I need an advice to how validate without spring validation. I need to use the messageresource for internationalization.

Comment: before calling service method "richiestaProduzione()", put an if check for validation. if validation fails, then do this "return new ResponseEntity<>("issuerMunicipalityCode is empty", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);"

Comment: Could you sensi me an example?

Answer (score 0):

To continue further, here is how you can implement custom validation.

Add a validation to throw an exception when issueType is MIN and municipality code is empty/null.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = ProductionResponse.URL, produces = JWSMessageConverter.JWS_MEDIA_TYPE_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ProductionResponse> richiestaProduzione(@RequestParam("issuerType") String issuerType,
        @RequestParam("issuerCode") String issuerCode, @RequestParam("procedureId") String procedureId,
        @RequestBody ProductionRequestResource requestBody) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug("POST " + ProductionResponse.URL);

    if("MIN".equals(issuerType) && StringUtils.isEmpty(requestBody.getIssuerMunicipalityCode())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("IssuerMuncipalityCode can't be null when IssuerType is MIN");
    }

    try {
        ProductionResponse response = produzioneService.richiestaProduzione(requestBody);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ProductionResponse.ko(requestBody, e.getMessage(), requestBody.getNun()));
    }
}
```

Implement exception handler to catch the exceptions and build response body based on exception types. InvalidArgumentSuppliedException that was thrown above will be caught by below exception handler. Exception Handler is a best practice to handle exceptions in a separate component.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ScnSchedulerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidArgumentSuppliedException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidArgException(Exception ex) {
        ErrorResponseDTO errorDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO();
        errorDTO.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex) {
        ErrorResponseDTO errorDTO = new ErrorResponseDTO();
        errorDTO.setMessage("Internal server error occurred.");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

In the exception handler, wrap the error messages in a pojo object.

```
public class ErrorResponseDTO {

    private String errorMessage;

}
```

Comment: I write a custom validator and i obtain the PathVariable field with `HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();`