# Spring 4 validator NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm using Java 1.7.0_09, Spring 4 totally xml-free, Intellij Idea 13.1.6 and Tomcat 1.0.151. I have problem with jsr 303 validation. I'm trying to validate form passed to spring via POST method. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=POST)
    public String processRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "registerForm";
        }

        repository.save(spitter);
        return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUsername();
    }
```

Here is my bean:

```
public class Spitter {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=16)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, max=25)
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public Spitter() {}

    public Spitter(String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this(null, username, password, firstName, lastName, email);
    }

    public Spitter(Long id, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>

    <sf:form method="POST" commandName="spitter">
        First name: <sf:input path="firstName"/><br/>
        <sf:errors path="firstName" /><br/>
        Last name: <sf:input path="lastName"/><br/>
        Email: <sf:input path="email"/><br/>
        Username: <sf:input path="username"/><br/>
        Password: <sf:input path="password"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
    </sf:form>
```

Maven file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My Tomcat lib jars:

```
annotations-api.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-storeconfig.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
catalina.jar
ecj-4.4.jar
el-api.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
servlet-api.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-jni.jar
tomcat-spdy.jar
tomcat-util-scan.jar
tomcat-util.jar
tomcat-websocket.jar
websocket-api.jar
```

Validation seems not firing at all. Regardless of input put in form condition

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
```

is always false.

To debug this I write some unit test. Here it is:

```
@Test
public void carIsValid() {
    Spitter car = new Spitter("aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaa");

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Spitter>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(car);

    assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size());
}
```

And here validation works like a charm. Because of that I try to validate input form like that so I change my controller code to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=POST)
public String processRegistration(Spitter spitter) {

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

    if (validator.validate(spitter).size() > 0) {
        return "registerForm";
    }

    repository.save(spitter);
    return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUsername();
}
```

But now I get error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validation
```

Could you tell me why validation dont work automatically and why when I try to validate it manually it works only in unit test and crashes in controller code?

Comment: Dependency to `javax.validation` seems redundant to me. `hibernate-validator` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Spring bean validation and JSR-303 validation.

I had this same issue and it was solved by following the tutorial referenced in this answer:
[Using both JSR-303 and Traditional Bean Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835122/using-both-jsr-303-and-traditional-bean-validation/6869950#6869950)